# Convert df's rows into matrices inside an array

Tags: r

I have a `nxp` data frame and I want to convert it to an array with `n` matrices where each matrix is, let's say, `ixj` where `i+j = p`. Considering the following reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~x1, ~x2, ~x3, ~x4,
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The desired result is an array with 2 matrices similar to the one produced by:

```
array(1:8, c(2,2,2))
```

Would anybody have an efficient method to obtain such results in high dimensional data frames?

Comment: Try `df %>% split(row(.)) %>% unlist %>% array(., c(2, 2, 2))`

Answer (score 2):

With baseR and `array`:

```
array(t(df), c(2, 2, 2))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8
```